# After upgrade Angular 10 to 14 @gilsdav/ngx-translate-router giving error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

After upgrading from angular 10 to angular 14 `@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router` giving error. I have updated the package to latest version but still getting this error [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to update @gilsdav/ngx-translate-router to 5.0.0